# Android MVVM: Should the view notify the view-model for every user interaction even trivial ones (only have UI consequence/no data)

Tags: android, mvvm, architectural-patterns

According to my little knowledge:

> In MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) architectural pattern, the view should
>   notify the view-model for user interactions such as button clicks. The
>   view-model responds by updating its observable data streams (LiveData)
>   that the view would be observing. Hence the view would update the UI
>   and the user sees the result.

But lets consider some trivial case when the user actions have only UI consequence with no data related or manipulated. For example: a Button that when clicked, toggles the visibility of another UI widget.

My question is how to handle this simple case while still applying MVVM correctly?
Should I directly update the UI without notifying the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all for all UI related things, you should absolutely notify ViewModel. You can define the event as follow in the ViewModel. BTW _itemClickedEvent defined for encapsulation.

```
private val _itemClickedEvent = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

var itemClickedEvent: LiveData<Boolean> = _itemClickedEvent

fun itemClickedEvent(state: Boolean) {
    _itemClickedEvent.value = state
}
```

After that you can call itemClickedEvent via viewModel object for your scenario.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.itemClickedEvent(true)
        }
```

By observing LiveData you can do your visibility or any other UI related things as below

```
viewModel.itemClickedEvent.observe(this, Observer {isItemClicked->
        if(isItemClicked){
            // Do your changes
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.